# XCode (Swift 3): Not showing NavigationBar in ViewController

Tags: xcode, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm trying to show a `NavigationBar` with a `Bar Button Item`.

I drag and drop the elements in the StoryBoard and press `Reset to Suggested Constraints`, but the `NavigationBar` doesn't appear.

I tried setting the constraints manually in a different ways but can set it right.

There is a way to use layouts instead of constraints? In Android it is more simple, but using XCode and Swift I always have problems with the UI.

The segue that appears in top of the ViewController comes from a SWRevealController. That segue has `sw_front` as identifier, and class `SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController`.

Please give some ideas about how to fix it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I fixed it some days ago.

In conclusion:

- It is better to generate the `NavigationBar` creating a **segue** from the root of the `NavigationView` to another `ViewController`.
- At least for me, the `SideMenu` is a better option (instead of SWReveal): it is more clear to get it working without a lot of changes in the StoryBoard: https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu